# Expected value of a sample

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I am unsure of how to solve this question. I know from examples questions that expected value of a sample is usually very close to the population mean. However, it says to compute the expected value and I don't know how to do that or how to find the sample's standard deviation. I have tried going through various statistics textbooks, but I cannot find an example to solve this question:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** You know that $X\sim N(2.835,0.15^2)$, assuming that $X_1,...X_{100}$ is a random sample of $X$ then 
$$E[\overline{X}]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{100}E[X_i]$$

$$Var(\overline{X})=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{100}Var(X_i)$$

I do not know what you've learned but if $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $\overline{X}\sim N(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n})$

If you are learning about inference, I recommend to take a look at some of these 2 books

[Statistical Inference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534243126)

[Introduction to the Theory of Statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070854653)

**EDIT:**
$E[\overline{X}]=\frac{1}{100}\sum_{i=1}^{100}E[X_i]=\frac{1}{100}(E[X_1]+E[X_2]+\cdots+E[X_{100}])=\frac{1}{100}100*E[X_1]=2.835$ where the last equality comes from the fact of the independence of the variables

Comment: I hope you don't mind me asking, but I keep seeing this notation N(something, something2) in my book and I don't understand what it is. You used 2.835 there, so how did you come up with it or what is that?

Comment: @Kelbe $X\sim N(2.835,0.15^2)$ is a notation for Normal random variable with $\mu=2.835$ and $\sigma^2=0.15^2$

Comment: Thank you John. I'll check out the books you mentioned.

Comment: How would I use the formula to compute the expected value? I don't know Xi or the average for each sample.

Comment: @Kelbe Take a look at my latest edition, you can do like this to find the variance $Var(\overline{X})$